# How to display shop timing in a week nodejs

Tags: node.js, loops, filter

I have a key array of objects which user have for days and their timings for their shop i.e

user A -

```
{
"name" : "shop1",
    "timings" : [ 
        {
            "Monday" : "10am to 7pm"
        }, 
        {
            "Thursday" : "Closed"
        }, 
        {
            "Friday" : "9am to 6pm"
        }, 
        {
            "Sunday" : "Closed"
        }, 
        {
            "Wednesday" : "10am to 7pm"
        }, 
        {
            "Tuesday" : "10am to 7pm"
        }, 
        {
            "Saturday" : "10am to 7pm"
        }
    ]}
```

Now I need to show these timing by days in frontend i.e
Monday-Saturday:9am to 7pm, Thursday,Sunday: Closed

So far I've tried to loop them and searched all days which are closed i.e

```
      function filterByValue(array, string) {
        return array.filter(o =>
            Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())));
    }
   let closedDays = filterByValue(element.timings, 'Closed')
console.log("whtt",closedDays); // [{name: 'Lea', country: 'Italy'}]
let res = closedDays.map(x => Object.keys(x)[0]);
```

but for open days I can't figure out any suitable solution which can be used here. It would be a great help if you suggest something

Comment: For open days, irrespective of timings on each day you want to show `9am to 7pm`?

Comment: no its average timing for all days if timings are different for days @Nithish

Comment: the minimum is 9 am and the maximum is 7 pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const timings = [{"Monday": "10am to 7pm"}, {"Thursday": "Closed"}, {"Friday": "9am to 6pm"}, {"Sunday": "Closed"}, {"Wednesday": "10am to 7pm"}, {"Tuesday": "10am to 7pm"}, {"Saturday": "10am to 7pm"}];
const weekDaysInOrder = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

//Step1 little change list of objects
const newTimings = changeTimingsStructure(timings);

let obj = {}
sortTimings(newTimings).forEach(el => {
    if (el.timing in obj) {
        const maxIndex = Math.max(...obj[el.timing].map(el => el.indexOfDay));
        if (maxIndex + 1 < el.indexOfDay && el.timing !== 'Closed') {
            obj = pushToObjectArr(el.timing + '-v2', el, obj);
        } else {
            obj = pushToObjectArr(el.timing, el, obj);
        }
    } else {
        obj = pushToObjectArr(el.timing, el, obj);
    }
})

displayTimings(obj);

function changeTimingsStructure(timings) {
    const newTimings = [];
    timings.forEach(day => {
        const dayName = Object.keys(day)[0]
        const timing = day[dayName];

        newTimings.push({
            day: dayName,
            timing,
            indexOfDay: weekDaysInOrder.findIndex(dayInWeek => dayInWeek === dayName)
        })
    })

    return newTimings;
}

function sortTimings(timings) {
    return timings.sort(((a, b) => a.indexOfDay - b.indexOfDay));
}

function pushToObjectArr(key, el, obj) {
    if (key in obj) {
        obj[key].push(el);
    } else {
        obj[key] = [el]
    }

    return obj
}

function displayTimings(obj) {
    let closedText = '';
    for (const groupOfDays in obj) {
        if (groupOfDays !== 'Closed') {
            if (obj[groupOfDays].length > 1) {
                console.log(`${obj[groupOfDays][0].day} - ${obj[groupOfDays][obj[groupOfDays].length - 1].day}: ${groupOfDays}`);
            } else {
                console.log(`${obj[groupOfDays][0].day}: ${obj[groupOfDays][0].timing}`);
            }
        } else {
            closedText = `${obj[groupOfDays].map(dayObj => dayObj.day).join(', ')}: Closed`;
        }
    }
    console.log(closedText);
}
```

Try this, final output: [image]

Comment: thanks for your response ...but can i display time like monday-wednesday: 10am to 7pm,  something like that? that's why I thought I could take average time (min and max) so that all can group . is it possible?

Comment: @pu i updated my post, see this piece of shit code: D I think it works as you want

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created this utility in order to format the input as per your expected output.

```js
let data = {name:'shop1',timings:[{Monday:'10am to 7pm'},{Thursday:'Closed'},{Friday:'9am to 6pm'},{Sunday:'Closed'},{Wednesday:'10am to 7pm'},{Tuesday:'10am to 7pm'},{Saturday:'10am to 7pm'}]};

const formatData = data => {
  return data.reduce(
    (result, d) => {
      const value = Object.values(d)[0];
      const key = Object.keys(d)[0];
      if (value === 'Closed') {
        result.closed.days.push(key);
        if (!result.closed.values) {
          result.closed.value = value;
        }
      } else {
        result.open.days.push(key);
        result.open.timings.push(value);
      }

      return result;
    },
    {
      closed: { days: [], value: '' },
      open: { days: [], timings: [] },
    }
  );
};

const formattedData = formatData(data.timings);

const formatTimings = timings => {
  const formattedTimings= timings.reduce((result, time) => {
    const times = time
        .split('to')
        .map(t => parseInt(t.replace(/\D+/g, '')))
        .filter(Boolean);
        result.from.push(times[0]);
        result.to.push(times[1]);

        return result
  }, {from :[], to: []});

return `${Math.min(...formattedTimings.from)}am to ${Math.max(...formattedTimings.to)}pm`
};

const openDaysTimings = formatTimings(formattedData.open.timings);

const displayTimings = (days, time) => {
  return `${days.join(", ")}: ${time}`
}


console.log(displayTimings(formattedData.closed.days, formattedData.closed.value));
console.log(displayTimings(formattedData.open.days, openDaysTimings));
```

Comment: it's not working correctly with time like 10:30,10:39 etc

Comment: Sorry @pu, for the snippet I have provided I didn't consider 10:30 etc times. I assumed only time in hrs itself. Will work on it and comeback.